# Is this equality true? Why? Why not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $$ \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} - \frac{1}{a^2} \right) \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

I already know that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi a)}$. With that in mind, we know that the series converges in for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ (**Is that right?**)

Also, all terms are positive so the series converges absolutely. Hence,

$$= \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} \right) + \left( \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} \right) + \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{a^2} \right) = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} \right) + \left( \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^2} \right) \right) = \\ \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(-n)^2} \right) + \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \right) = \\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Now, how do I justify the continuity of the series which enabled me to do this algebraic trick?

Comment: What you need to show is absolute convergence.  That will justify rearranging the terms of the series.

Comment: The series does not converge for $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ (since then it has an infinite term). To prove continuity, you can show that the series converges locally uniformly (or compactly) on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ (or on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, but it's the same proof, basically).

Comment: @TimRaczkowski, I claimed that all terms are positive. Hence, there's also an absolute convergence, but is that enough?

Comment: @DanielFischer, Could you explain why is it true that for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ the series does not converge?

Comment: Yes, any rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series will produce the same sum.

Comment: @AlonAlon If $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, the sum contains a term with $n = -a$, then $\frac{1}{((-a)+a)^2} = \frac{1}{0^2} = \infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, How can I show the series converges uniformly?

Comment: It converges only _locally_ uniformly. Take a compact $K\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ if you want to treat only real $a$), and estimate $$\sum_{\lvert n\rvert \geqslant N} \frac{1}{\lvert n+a\rvert^2}$$ uniformly for all $a\in K$, where you choose $N$ large enough (depending on $K$; say if $\lvert a\rvert \leqslant N/2$ for all $a\in K$ you're good).

Comment: So basically, for $a\in K= [0,1]$ we can compare the to $$ \sum_{\left|n\right|\ge N} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi a)}$$
as a function of $a$, is an even meromorphic function with a double pole in zero, as the square of a meromorphic function with a simple pole in zero:
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}=\frac{1}{z}+\zeta(2) z+\ldots $$
it happens that:
$$ \lim_{z\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}\right)=\lim_{z\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}+2\zeta(2)+\ldots\right)=2\zeta(2)$$
as expected.